# HTTP header response data

Tags: php, http-headers

I want to calculate the size in bytes of the http response headers and data in PHP.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Whose response headers, in what context?

Comment: Are you serving the response headers, or expecting a response from another server that your PHP application contacts, say using cURL?

Comment: the requirement is to log http request and response size.

Comment: i managed to find the http request size using getallheaders(), now i want to calculate the size of the response data as well as size of http headers sent during response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't measure the size of the response headers from your PHP code because the webserver may change them before serving them up. Only the webserver can measure this - and you don't say what webserver you are using. With Apache, install mod_logio and start recording %I, %O and %B

Comment: getheaders() would give you the complete header response, but it would add to additional call

Comment: @RJ: only after the headers have been flushed (and only if the encoding is not chunked)

Comment: Could you explain "encoding is not chunked", i didn't get it

Comment: @RJ: if the encoding is chunked, then the webserver will send a set of headers, then the first chunk of the body, then more content which is effectively a header before the next chaunk - your PHP code doesn't know where the webserver has split the body